# basic rails model has_many and belongs_to with group by date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm a rails newbie so pardon if this is a basic question. I'm setting up some models and the relationships should be pretty basic, but I'm a little stuck in the best way to set everything up.

I'm trying to display a list of seminars that have different times. Here are my two tables:

```
create_table "seminars", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end

create_table "seminar_times", :force => true do |t|
  t.datetime "start_date"
  t.datetime "end_date"
  t.integer  "seminar_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end
```

I'd like to display my seminars at localhost:3000/seminars like so:

```
Intro To Rails      Aug 1   3-5pm and 6-8pm
How To Juggle       Aug 10  6-8pm
Stackoverflow Rocks Aug 13  2-5pm or 6-8pm
```

One seminar can have many different seminar times (which is why i put them into two separate tables). To do this normally with straight SQL I'd join the tables, order by start_date, then group by DAY and by seminar id.

How would I do this the "rails way"?

Here's what I've done so far, but it doesn't seem like the right way to go.

Seminar model:

```
class Seminar < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :seminar_times, :dependent => :destroy
  validates :name, :presence => true
end
```

SeminarTime model:

```
class SeminarTime < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :end_date, :seminar_id, :start_date
  belongs_to :seminar, :foreign_key => 'seminar_id'
  default_scope :order => 'start_date'
end
```

seminars_controller:

```
def index
  @seminars = SeminarTime.group('date(start_date), seminar_id') #THIS LINE ESPECIALLY SEEMS WRONG TO ME
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @seminars }
  end
end
```

seminar_times_controller:

```
def index
  @seminar_times = SeminarTime.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @seminar_times }
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :seminars 
resources :seminar_times
root to: 'static_pages#home'
match '/seminars',    to: 'seminars#index'
```

views/seminars/index.html.erb:

```
#this also needs some work. i'm not sure how to loop into that group by statement
<% @seminars.each do |seminar| %>
  <%= seminar.seminar.name %>
  <%= seminar.start_date %>
  <%= seminar.end_date %>
<% end %>
```

I've tried also getting everything through the seminar_times_controller and then routing /seminars to:
    match '/seminars',    to: 'seminar_times#index'
but that also seems kinda off to me.

Hopefully I'm being clear enough. Any guidance is much appreciated. Thanks!

---

My app evolved some since I asked this question. I ended up adding some categories, so I made a shared module so I could use my sorting code throughout the app. The sort and grouping looks like this:

```
module Shared
  def self.category_group_by_day(categories_array)
    seminars = Seminar.joins(:seminar_times, :categories).
      where(:categories => {:name => categories_array}).
      where("date(start_time) > ?", DateTime.now)

    seminars.sort_by! { |s| s.start_date }
    seminar_days = seminars.group_by { |s| [s.start_date.beginning_of_day, s.course_id] }
  end
end
```

I call it in my controller like this:

```
@seminar_days = Shared::category_group_by_day(['Free Seminar', 'Online Seminar'])
```

And then in my view:

```
<% @seminar_days.keys.sort.each do |day| %> 
 <%= @seminar_days[day].first.course_name %>
  <%= day.to_s.to_date.strftime("%b %e") %> <%= day.to_s.to_date.strftime("%a") %>
    <% for seminar in @seminar_days[day] %>
      <div>
        <%= seminar.start_date.strftime("%l").strip %>—<%= seminar.end_date.strftime("%l").strip %> <%= seminar.end_date.strftime("%p") %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: you can omit the :foreign_key => 'seminar_id' - that's the convention.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't consider myself advanced enough to give you an answer on the ultimate "rails way to do it" I've fiddled around a bit and found this solution:

in SeminarsController:

```
def index
  @seminars_ordered_2 = CourseTime.order(:start_date).map{ |t| t.seminar}.uniq
...
```

and in views/seminars/index.html.erb:

```
    <table border ="1">
    <% @seminars_ordered_2.each do |seminar| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= seminar.name %></td>
        <td><% seminar.seminar_times.each do | st | %>
            <%=st.start_date%> till <%=st.end_date%>
            <br>
             <% end%>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
    </table>
```

this gives something similar to what you wanted.

I couldn't find info wether Array uniq is guaranteed to retain the order, that is, if [2,3,2].uniq always returns [2,3] - it seems to, though.

I've experimented with combining group by and order by in two ways:

```
     @seminars_ordered_1 =Seminar.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN course_times ON course_times.seminar_id = seminars.id GROUP BY course_times.seminar_id ORDER BY course_times.start_date ')
     @seminars_ordered_2 = CourseTime.group(:seminar_id).map{|t| t.seminar}
```

but both do the grouping first, resulting in orders that do not guarantee that the very first date always is returned first (the second depending on the ordering defined in your default scope).

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I like the map solution, although it doesn't quite get what I want. Your queries sort on the seminar name and return all their times. What I want is to have each DAY listed and then list each seminar time for that day (one day can have multiple times, but if there are two different seminars on the same day they should be listed separately). So it would group by day and by seminar. i.e: July 4 Rails is Great 3-5pm or 6-8pm. July 4 Intro to Django 9-10pm